# Java equivalence of Intrinsic and explicit Global locking

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I want to know if the two scenarios are equivalent or not in a multithreaded environment.

```
private final Lock globalLock = new ReentrantLock();
```

Scenario 1

```
public void addListener( Listener listener ) {
    globalLock.lock();
    try{
    //blah blah
    }finally {
        globalLock.unlock();
    }
}

public void removeListener( Listener listener ) {
    globalLock.lock();
    try{
    //blah blah
    }finally {
        globalLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Scenario 2

```
public synchronized addListener( Listener listener ) {
}

public synchronized removeListener( Listener listener ) {
}
```

I think the first scenario has race conditions in a multithreaded environment because if Thread A calls addListener() method **before** Thread B calls removeListener(), there is still the potential for Thread B to acquire the lock before Thread A even though Thread A invoked addListener() before Thread B invoked removeListener(). Is this hypothesis correct or Java guarantees that at least one statement of the method will be executed before the Thread is scheduled out.

Comment: yes, globalLock is a global final field

Comment: The situation you described is not race condition. Calls to addListener and removeListener from different threads cannot be considered in terms "before" or "after".

Answer (score 1):

They are functionally equivalent (assuming `globalLock` is a final instance variable).

In your first example, if two threads call the two methods simultaneously, only one of them will be able to acquire the lock and the second one will have to wait until the first one releases the lock.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question is, if two threads call the methods independently BUT Thread A calls Before Thread B, can Thread B acquire the Lock before thread A? Effectively I want to know if given addlistener() is called Before removeListener() by separate threads, this implementation provides a guarantee of Program Order?

Comment: Not sure I understand: either you use synchronization to ensure that Thread A calls the method before Thread B and that is what will happen or you don't and it will be random. The same applies to the synchronized methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what global lock is. If it is an instance field

```
private final Lock globalLock = new ReentrantLock();

public void addListener( Listener listener ) {
    globalLock.lock();
    ...
```

then the answer is yes, these two scenarios are equivalent

Comment: please see my comment to assylias

Answer (score 0):

They are **not** exactly equivalent in a multithreaded environment.
Yes functionally they are same as suggested by assylias.

But their is big difference among the two approaches.
That big difference is that in scenario 1 your **lock is private**. 
and hence its a good practice because u r sure nobody else can own your lock.
While the scenario is not a very good approach( except in some cases) because
any other user can hold the lock any longer as now your **lock is public**.

So functionally equivalent but by design they are different.